# How to go about the .csv file which contains text lines with commas?

Tags: r

I am using the `read.delim` function but since the text lines I am reading also contains comments where users have used commas (","), the comments get divided into two or more columns.

Below are two lines from the data set:

> @Zillaman u just aite all types of food at Zina crib and didnt even think about me!!!!,0
>
> I must have been only 11 when Mr Peepers started. It was a must see for the whole family, I believe on Sun...,1

The first line gets read properly. The "0" is read in the next column. The second line gets broken into three columns, with the last column containing the "1"

```
dataset_original = read.delim('TrainingData.csv', 
                              quote = "",
                              row.names = NULL, 
                              stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                              header = F, as.is = F,
                              colClasses = "character",
                              blank.lines.skip = T,
                              sep = ",")
```

Comment: Could you give us a sample of what's inside `TrainingData.csv`?

Comment: Here is the screenshot,

Comment: if the comments are quote-delimited, we can help. If they're not, you're probably screwed.

Comment: You failed to link the screenshot in your comment. Instead of posting a screenshot, please **cut and paste text from a few lines into an edit of your question** ...

Comment: Well, I am not allowed to upload a screenshot yet. Nonetheless I have attached a pic and platform has converted it in a link. I am not sure if you can check it or not.

Comment: maybe you can neglect the comment text by `skip = n`.

Comment: @DarrenTsai the dataset has more than 12,00,000 lines. I am not sure which all lines to skip

Comment: @BenBolker, I guess you're right...dataset doesn't contain a proper comment structure. It has been scrapped from Twitter and few movie review sites. I have been assigned to read the dataset, gauge the nature of the text by the 0 or 1 assigned to it at the last and train the model to mark the test set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reading all the lines individually and then separating text and target columns afterwards.

Try this:

```
df= read.delim('TrainingData.csv',
               quote = "",
               row.names = NULL,
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
               header = F, as.is = F,
               colClasses = "character",
               blank.lines.skip = T,
               sep = "\n")


df$target = regmatches(df$V1, regexpr(pattern = "[^,]*$", text = df$V1))
df$V1 = sub(pattern = ",[^,]*$", replacement = "", x = df$V1)
```

where `df` stands for `dataset_original`

#### Example:

With a file containing:

```
hello,0
world,1
not,right,1
this,one,is,even,worse,0
```

This method returns:

```
> df
                      V1 target
1                  hello      0
2                  world      1
3              not,right      1
4 this,one,is,even,worse      0
```

Comment: This worked I guess... I am still checking for irregularities.

Comment: Yup... Your trick worked. Thanks. Now I am stuck with memory distribution. Corpus became as huge as 4.6 GB. It took me 3 hours just to treat the stopwords from the corpus.

Comment: Thanks... I wasn't knowing that... I am a newbie to Stack ! I accepted the ans. Though, I am not able to tag you in my comments...

Answer (score 1):

If we read the file by using `readLines()`, we can afterwards split on the last comma.

```
write(x="@Zillaman u just aite all types of food at Zina crib and didnt even think about me!!!!,0

I must have been only 11 when Mr Peepers started. It was a must see for the whole family, I believe on Sun...,1", 
file="file.txt")

gg <- readLines("file.txt")

spl <- strsplit(gg, ",(?=[^,]+$)", perl=TRUE)
dtf <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, spl), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

dtf
#                                                     V1  V2
# 1 @Zillaman u just (...) didnt even think about me!!!!   0
# 2 I must have been (...) family, I believe on Sun...     1
```